# extract hash digits from string

Tags: python, json, extract

How can I extract only the hash digits in the quotations in various strings such as:

```
[file:hashes.'MD5' = '547334e75ed7d4eea2953675b07986b4']

[file:hashes.'SHA1' = '82d29b52e35e7938e7ee610c04ea9daaf5e08e90']

[file:hashes.'SHA256' = 'ff3b45ecfbbdb780b48b4c829d2b6078d8f7673d823bedbd6321699770fa3f84']
```

I need to extract the digits and insert into a table using this script:

```
if item['hash'][:12]=='[file:hashes':    #it finds the hash string from Json dic like above lists
     if item['hash'][22:-2] not in hash_column:    #extracts the digits but only for MD5
          insert_hash_table(item['hash'][22:-2])   #insert the hash digit
```

So in the above example if the strings before the '=' changes due to different hashes then I won't be able to be consistent with my piece of code. Is there anyway to extract only the digits after '=' inside the quotations for all type of hashes ? - e.g. **82d29b52e35e7938e7ee610c04ea9daaf5e08e90**

Comment: Would you like to keep the hash type along with the hash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could split a string using '=' as a delimiter. Something like this:

```
hash = "file:hashes.'MD5' = '547334e75ed7d4eea2953675b07986b4'"

result = hash.split('=')[1].strip().strip("'")
print(result)
```

This code gives me the result:

```
547334e75ed7d4eea2953675b07986b4
```

Comment: that was a quick fix and thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Try ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/FJ01tY/1)):

```py
import re

s = """\
[file:hashes.'MD5' = '547334e75ed7d4eea2953675b07986b4']
[file:hashes.'SHA1' = '82d29b52e35e7938e7ee610c04ea9daaf5e08e90']
[file:hashes.'SHA256' = 'ff3b45ecfbbdb780b48b4c829d2b6078d8f7673d823bedbd6321699770fa3f84']"""

pat = re.compile(r"=\s*'([^']+)'")

for m in pat.findall(s):
    print(m)
```

Prints:

```
547334e75ed7d4eea2953675b07986b4
82d29b52e35e7938e7ee610c04ea9daaf5e08e90
ff3b45ecfbbdb780b48b4c829d2b6078d8f7673d823bedbd6321699770fa3f84
```

Comment: this was a very useful answer and have given me the solution. However the above answer seemed to be a faster solution for me code. Thank you regardless.